# htaccess - 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

```
 http://www.mysite.com/index.php?channels=browse&channel_id=1&sort=rated
```

to

```
 http://www.mysite.com/category/cars/?r_sortby=highest_rated&r_orderby=desc
```

Can someone to help-me with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: where is category and cars coming from?

Comment: channel_id=1 becomes cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?channels=browse&channel_id=1&sort=rated\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /category/cars/?r_sortby=highest_rated&r_orderby=desc? [R=301,L]
```

EDIT:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /watch.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It works. But, if I add the following code in my `.htaccess` is not working 
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /watch\.php\?tag=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /watch.php?tag=$1 [L]`

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work when you add in the other stuff?

Comment: Yes. And your code works. I added also another caregory: moto. channel_id=2 becomes moto (category/moto/). That works too. But if I add my code above mentioned, is not working.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not working? Does anything redirect or do you get an error?

Comment: I use Wordoress. "Nothing Found Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post." The posts from cotagory are gone.

Comment: If i delete `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /watch.php?tag=$1 [L]` is working :)

Comment: If you add the `rewritecond` and rule in my post above to below your current rules, would it still work?

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer, replace the last part of the other code with that.

Comment: Error: `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: I think that is working. As I told you, I use Wordpress, I tried this: 1. your first code, 2. `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /watch\.php\?tag=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=301,L]`, 3. wordpress code 4. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /watch.php?tag=$1 [L]`